# getURL with user, pwd and AppID

Tags: r, rcurl

I'm trying to make the following request :

```
library("RCurl")

getURL("https://api.example.com/resource",
userpwd ="username:password",param="ApplicationID")
```

But I have this error :

```
The required parameter 'Username' was not found.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this work for you: `opts = curlOptions(userpwd = "username:password", param= "ApplicationID")    getURL("url",.opts=opts)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
opts = curlOptions(userpwd = "user:swd", param= "AppID") 
getURL("url",.opts=opts)
```

Comment: I've try but I get the same error :  The required parameter 'Username' was not found.

Comment: I hope "username" used here is for demo purpose and you are using the required username.

Comment: Yes sure "username" is only for demo like "password" and "ApplicationID" I think I don't put the "ApplicationID" in the right place in the function getURL.

Comment: I try to use JSON as well but I have the same error
fromJSON(
  getURL(link,body={
  '{
  "CreateServiceToken_Request_1": {
    "ApplicationID": "AppID",
    "Username": "user",
    "Password": "swd"
  }
    }'
})
)
The required parameter 'Username' was not found."

Comment: Going by your json, I have edited the answer...are you using the variable "Usename" instead of it's value "user" in the request?

Comment: Actually my user is : trkd-demo-wm@thomsonreuters.com